# Configure Git 2-factor authentication tokens using Git cli

Tags: git, github

I have enabled 2-factor authentication for my Github account.
So, I'm unable to access my repositories from my local git command line...
How can I configure my 2-factor authentication tokens, username , password in my local system so that i can use git CLI without needing to provide any credentials..

Comment: You need to create an access token associated to your GitHub account and use that as your password from the command line. Here's a link to an article that describes how to do that: https://help.github.com/en/articles/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line

Comment: If you tell us what OS you're using, we can recommend a credential helper that will work for your system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Enrico pointed out in his comment, you need to create a [GitHub Personal Access Token](https://help.github.com/en/articles/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line) to use the git cli with GitHub 2FA. Once you've created a token, you use that instead of a password on the command line. Personal access tokens only work for git over HTTPS (so if you've previously cloned a repo over ssh, you'll need to change the remote--this is all documented in the GitHub link above).

In addition, you probably want to [configure a credential helper](https://help.github.com/en/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git) (or Keychain on MacOS) to cache your access token, e.g.:

`git config --global credential.helper cache`

Answer (score 1):

I also didn't get it to work with 2FA so I started using ssh keys.
For a detailed instruction in how to set ssh keys up read this: [connecting to github with ssh](https://help.github.com/en/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh)

I think the problem is that git does not support 2FA so you cannot get it to work without rewriting git and then use your own version.